# WordPress map custom url to a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom URL structure to a WordPress based website.

for example:

```
example.com/machines             //list all machines in a table

example.com/machines?some=params //list filtered machines in a table

example.com/machines/1           //show single machine
```

The data will come from an external api i have already developed, via curl.

I cannot import the data into a custom post type as it is normalized over many tables, the business logic is complicated and the api is used by other devices anyway.

I have looked at the docs for [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), but the second parameter has me stumped:

```
$redirect
(string) (required) The URL you would like to actually fetch
```

Well I don't have a url to fetch, I want to run a function, that will act as a simple router - take the url parts, call the external api and return a template with the correct data.

Calling the API will be simple, but how i actually route the url to the function, and how I then load a template (utilizing existing WordPress header.php and footer.php) has me stumped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much googling and reading a few [good](https://roots.io/routing-wp-requests/) [resources](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/), I have found the solution.

**Step 1:** Use `add_rewrite_endpoint` to create a base url that will be mapped to a query variable:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'machines', EP_ROOT );
} );
```

**Step 2:** Visit the permalinks settings page and click "Save Changes" to flush the rewrite rules.

**Step 3:** Hook into the action `'template_redirect'` to actually do something when the url is hit:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( $machinesUrl = get_query_var( 'machines' ) ) {
        // var_dump($machinesUrl, $_GET);
        // $machinesURl contains the url part after example.com/machines
        // e.g. if url is example.com/machines/some/thing/else
        // then $machinesUrl == 'some/thing/else'
        // and params can be retrieved via $_GET

        // after parsing url and calling api, it's just a matter of loading a template:
        locate_template( 'singe-machine.php', TRUE, TRUE );

        // then stop processing
        die();
    }
});
```

**Step 4:** The only other thing to do is handle a hit to a url with no further parts to it e.g. `example.com/machines`.
It turns out that at some point within WordPress's guts, the empty string gets evaluated to false and thus skipped, so the final step is to hook into the filter `'request'` and set a default value:

```
add_filter( 'request', function( $vars = [] ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['machines'] ) && empty( $vars['machines'] ) ) {
        $vars['machines'] = 'default';
    }
    return $vars;
});
```

This can easily be improved by wrapping it all in a class(es).
The url parsing and template loading logic can be passed to a basic router, even a rudimentary MVC setup, loading routes from a file etc, but the above is the starting point.

Answer (score 2):

A simplier solution is to just create a new template redirect.

So assuming you loading `example.com/custom-url`

```
/**
 * Process the requests that comes to custom url.
 */
function process_request() {
    // Check if we're on the correct url
    global $wp;
    $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
    if($current_slug !== 'custom-url') {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if it's a valid request.
    $nonce = filter_input(INPUT_GET, '_wpnonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce,  'NONCE_KEY')) {
        die( __( 'Security check', 'textdomain' ) );
    }

    // Do your stuff here
    

    //
    die('Process completed' );
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'process_request', 0);
```

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely skip `add_rewrite_endpoint`, its useful if you intend to have multiple url paths to handle, such as the rest style setup i used when i originally wrote this.

Comment: Make sure to add a header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); I was using this code for a webhook for a payment provider. If you don't add the header the page will return a 404 so the the payment provider thought the request failed.